# Uncaught TypeError: c.color.tweenTo is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts for a project. Everything worked fine, and then, for no reason (I haven't changed anything), it was no longer working (partially).
I think the problem comes with how I load my js, but I can't find how to load them.

I got 2 modules which showed the speed and the rpm of a vehicule. [In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13hol.png), we can see that only the one for the rpm is loading. Before, the 2 of them were loading.
And also, I'm working with Ajax to make it go up and down in live, it was working, but now it doesn't work anymore.

Here's the error I have in the console : "Uncaught TypeError: c.color.tweenTo is not a function".

First, here's my script with the Highcharts :

```
    $(function () {

        $(window).on('load resize', function(){
            var div = $('#container-speed');
            //div.height(div.width() * 0.75);
            div = $('#container-rpm');
            //div.height(div.width() * 0.75);        
        });

        var gaugeOptions = {

            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge'
            },

            title: null,

            pane: {
                center: ['50%', '50%'],
                size: '100%',
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                background: {
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                    innerRadius: '60%',
                    outerRadius: '100%',
                    shape: 'arc'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },

            yAxis: {
                stops: [
                    [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                    [0.4, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                    [0.7, '#DF5353'] // red
                ],
                lineWidth:0,
                minorTickInterval: null,
                tickAmount: 2,
                title: {
                    y: -70
                },
                labels: {
                    y: 16
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        y: 5,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        useHTML: true
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart('container-speed', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 200,
                title: {
                    text: 'Speed'
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Speed',
                data: [0],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                           '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' km/h'
                }
            }]
        }));

        var chartRpm = Highcharts.chart('container-rpm', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, { //{y:.1f}
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 7000,
                title: {
                    text: 'RPM'
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'RPM',
                data: [0],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.f}</span><br/>' +
                           '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">tour / min</span></div>'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
                }
            }]
        }));

        setInterval(function () {
            var vitesse = document.getElementById('myValues').value;

            var point,
                newVal,
                inc;
            if (chartSpeed) {
                point = chartSpeed.series[0].points[0];
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
                newVal = point.y + inc;
                var vitessee =Math.round(vitesse);
                point.update(vitessee);
            }

            var rpm = document.getElementById('rpm').value;
            if (chartRpm) {
                point = chartRpm.series[0].points[0];
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
                newVal = point.y + inc;

            var rpmm =Math.round(rpm);

                point.update(rpmm);
                }
            }, 2000);  
        });
```

Here's my ajax :

```
    function auto_load(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "traite.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);

                $("#myValues").val(parseInt(data[0].vitesse));
                $("#rapport").html('<label style="font-size: 20px">Rapport de vitesse : <br /><span style="font-size: 30px;">' + data[0].rapport + '</span></label>');

                if (data[0].tour_minute > 2000)
                    $("#conseil").html('<h3>Il serait temps de passer la vitesse</h3>');
                else
                    $("#conseil").html('');


                $("#rpm").val(data[0].tour_minute);
                $("#conso").html('<label style="font-size: 30px">Consommation : <br /><span style="font-size: 50px;">' + data[0].consomation + '</span> L/100km </label>');

                var poll =  parseInt(data[0].consomation * 0.7 * 3.67 * 10);
                $("#pollution").html('<label style="font-size: 30px">Rejet de CO2 : <br /><span style="font-size: 50px;">' + poll + '</span> gCO2/km </label>');

                $(".round").html();
            } 
        });
    }
```

Here's how I load my js :

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script src="test2.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
```

the script test2.js is to initialize the diagrams I want

I've searched and tried to rearrange the js, but it didn't solved the problem. 
I tried putting the solid-jauge.js before the highcharts-more.js, but I got another error in the console : "Uncaught TypeError: c.init is not a function".

I've searched for a week to try and solve the problem, but I can't seem to find the error.

Thanks in advance for anyone who used their time to help me !
If the error is just a simple typo or something like that, I'm sorry if you have searched in all this code for naught.

Comment: your given code no where contain anything like `c.color.tweenTo`. So it's confusing

Comment: the `c.color.tweenTo` and the `c.init` are in the test2.js script, but since it's a huuuuge mess, I'm not putting it here.

Comment: this happens only when corresponding library file is not added or A jQuery library is not added before this third-party library.

Comment: but I do have a jQuery library added before all the highcharts script, that's why I don't understand how I got this error, and the thing is that it was working 1 week ago !

Comment: I think that you may try putting test2.js after your highcharts scripts. If this won't help it would be really helpful if you could post minimal working example showing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you and figured out it was due to the CDN hosted solid-guage.js being recently updated and incompatible with the local highcharts.js I was using. To fix it, pull the source from Highcharts (https://www.highcharts.com/download) and include the libs locally in your project. So instead of:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
```

Use:

```
<script src="lib/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="lib/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="lib/solid-gauge.js"></script>
```